# How to compute the time spent in meetings with others, from Outlook or Teams?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, meetings, report

I use Outlook for Mac version 16.42 and Microsoft Teams 1.3.00.26266. I also have an Office 365 subscription. I would like to automatically compute the time I spend in meetings with at least one other person, during the week, and generate a report which I can then use to analyze trends across weeks and months. It's ok to produce a simple csv file, with, e.g., a `Date` column and a `Duration` column - each row corresponds to a day, and `Duration` is the sum of the time spent in meetings with at least another person on that day. It's also ok to export the data to Excel, if this doesn't add too much of a complication.

Is there a (preferably simple) way to do this? The data source can be either Outlook or Teams - I see my meetings in both calendars, and they agree. I have access to Power Automate, in case that helps, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, features in Outlook client are quite limited. To achieve this, you might need some VBA methods. I did some research and found this related article. Hope this could be helpful to you. [3 Methods to report time spent on Meetings, Tasks and Journal items.](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/timespent.htm)

**Update:**

Also,  as @DeltaIV mentioned, [Microsoft MyAnalytics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/myanalytics-personal-analytics) is a very helpful tool to handle businesses like this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the first method requires VBA, which isn't available in Outlook for Mac: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac. The last method requires a paid-for add-on, so I should go through the hoops & loops of getting the vendor approved by our Sourcing department....I'll have a look at the second method (the one using Excel, the most complex) and let you know.

Comment: Okay, any update, please feel free to post back.

Comment: it looks like this tool which would do exactly what I asked for - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/myanalytics-personal-analytics. What about updating your answer, including this suggestion?

Comment: Okay, very willing to do that.

Comment: perfect! Answer accepted